# some models are visible even after z-test lequal in a custom depth mask shader UNITY.

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, depth-testing

While using some 3D models the depth Mask Shader which is having z-test as "LEqual" need to perform normally as in screenshot1

[screenshot1](https://www.optiwar.com/image/flags/screenshot1.PNG)

But it give result which shows grayscale outlined of that part of 3d model where it need to be hidden. [Take reference of screenshot2]

[screenshot2](https://www.optiwar.com/image/flags/screenshot2.PNG)

We have tried changing the ZTest from LEqual to Always which solves the problem a bit but again the object is partially visible.

```
Shader "Custom/mask" { 
SubShader { 
Tags {
"Queue" = "Geometry+10" 
"RenderType" = "Opaque" 
}

Lighting Off 
ZTest LEqual 
Cull Back 
ZWrite On 
ColorMask 0 
Blend One One 
Pass {Fog {Mode Off}}

} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you do an early Z-pass from the occluding mesh, which I guess is a reconstructed or motion tracked face? so the glasses are rendered with a standard material correct?

The mask material needs to be drawn ***early*** so the queue should be Geometry-10 or something. All the other tags are irrelevant except **ColorMask 0** .

Lighting and Fog are deprecated and Blend is of no use since you don't draw to the color buffer anyway (using ColorMask 0 it only draws the depth).